# Linux 6.7: /sys/class/graphics/fb0 is missing

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, hardware, amd-graphics, sysfs

What happened to this node/symlink? It used to be there for ages, linking to the primary display adapter, and I [cannot](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/3164) find it any longer with Linux 6.7.4. I've not found anything relevant in the changelog either.

Is this a bug? Or something has changed fundamentally?

I only have:

```
ls -la /sys/class/graphics/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 0 Feb  9 13:20 .
drwxr-xr-x. 79 root root 0 Feb  9 13:15 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 Feb  9 13:15 fbcon -> ../../devices/virtual/graphics/fbcon
```

Comment: The code is still there to create it in `drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbsysfs.c`. `e2af003210c6 ("fbdev/core: Add fb_device_{create,destroy}()")` changes this code path, but was already in 6.6. Most likely your driver has dropped fb support.

Comment: That's `amdgpu` but Alex Deucher from AMD didn't say it was the case. But then the driver is developed by multiple people, so he might not know.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bug? Or something has changed fundamentally?

The latter. fbdev has been superseeded by the more uniform, hence easier to use, and faster DRM subsystem. It might be that your AMD driver used to supply both interfaces, but lately dropped the old FB; my intel driver, for example, pretty certainly hadn't had that for a while.

Instead, I have `/dev/dri/card0`, as part of the "direct rendering interface" (which is the combination of the kernel-side DRM and user-side libraries/programs).

Comment: I’m not sure it’s specifically driver-related, it might be more global; my Intel-equipped laptop still has `fb0` on 6.6.6.

Comment: interesting (also, my favourite kernel revision)

Answer (score 0):

For those who used the old device, you can now resort to `/sys/class/drm/card1/device/` instead. Not sure how the numbering of `drm` works, as I've got the only card and it's numbered `1` where normally Linux counts everything from zero.